# How to pass data through VSCode URL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VSCode extension, which needs to receive data from a web app. In the web app, I call `vscode://file` to open VSCode, but I also need to pass data to it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer from this blog : [How to callback to your extension from outside Visual Studio Code](https://www.eliostruyf.com/callback-extension-vscode/)

It uses VSCode Extension API : `vscode.window.registerUriHandler`

1. Enter `vscode://<publisher>.<extension name>` Uri in the chrome address field.

> publisher and extension name is defined in `package.json`

2. Edit `extension.ts`

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const handleUri = (uri: vscode.Uri) => {
     console.log("uri",uri);  
  };

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerUriHandler({
      handleUri
    })
  );
}
```

Ensure that the window that extension is activated is always at the top level.